# Install Tomcat 8.5 through apt (apt-get)

Tags: apt, tomcat, tomcat8

Does anybody know if and when this will be available for Ubuntu Server 16.04? As of now, installing Tomcat through apt you get version 8.0.45.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer to "if and when Tomcat 8.5 will be available for Ubuntu Server 16.04?" is *if -* NO and *when -* in Ubuntu 17.10 and later. You have already written in a comment that you do not want to download Tomcat 8.5 and install it manually in Ubuntu 16.04.

Apache Tomcat 8 version 8.5 (*tomcat8*) will not be available in the Ubuntu 16.04 default repositories, but it it will be available in the official Ubuntu repositories starting in Ubuntu 17.10 which will be released in October, 2017. In Ubuntu 17.10 and later open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install tomcat8
```

Apache Tomcat 9 (*tomcat9*) will be available in the official Ubuntu repositories starting in Ubuntu 19.04. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install tomcat9
```

Comment: Indeed, current version for the "tomcat8" package is 8.0.32 for 16.04LTS (https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/tomcat8).
I was wondering, how do you know this package will not be updated to 8.5? Is there documentation that can be consulted about this?

Comment: The easiest way to get tomcat8 version 8.5.21 is to upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 when it is released two months from now in April. I haven't seen any milestones except for that.